# How do I deal with form in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I was dealing with forms in laravel, I have written the code but once i click on the button to submit the form it's just reset the page

Here is my view create.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <form action="/p" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            @csrf

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-8 offset-2">

                    <div class="row">
                        <h1>Add New Post</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="caption" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Post Caption</label>

                        <input id="caption"
                               type="text"
                               class="form-control{{ $errors->has('caption') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
                               name="caption"
                               value="{{ old('caption') }}"
                               autocomplete="caption" autofocus>

                        @if ($errors->has('caption'))
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('caption') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                        @endif
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <label for="image" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Post Image</label>

                        <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="image" name="image">

                        @if ($errors->has('image'))
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('image') }}</strong>
                        @endif
                    </div>

                    <div class="row pt-4">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary">Add New Post</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
@endsection
```

And my PostsController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
    public function create(){
        return view('posts.create');
    }

    public function store(){
        $data = request()->validate([
            'caption' => 'required',
            'image' => ['required', 'image'],
        ]);

        Post::create($data);

        dd(request()->all());
    }
}
```

my routes web.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/p/create', 'PostsController@create');
Route::post('/p', 'PostsController@create');

Route::get('/profile/{user}', 'ProfilesController@index')->name('profile.show');
```

The validation is not working and every time I click on the button, it resets everything. Kidly Help me sort this out

Post model

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('caption');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->index('user_id');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this line in your `web.php` file, from

```
Route::post('/p', 'PostsController@create');
```

to

```
Route::post('/p/store', 'PostsController@store')->name('p.store');
```

As you can see in the modification above, you were pointing to the wrong Controller method.

Additionally, it is best practice to use named route.

With the above named route, you can now use the route helper without worrying about the url like this in your form:

```
<form action="{{ route('p.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
</form>
```

**UPDATE 1**:

I didn't catch this earlier. Your Controller method must have at least the `Request` object as parameter in the definition for `POST` requests. Also update your validation logic.

Update your `store()` method to this

```php
public function store(Request $request){
    $request->validate([
        'caption' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg',
    ]);

    Post::create($request->input());

    dd($request->all());
}
```

Observe that you were using the global request helper `request()` previously. You don't need to do that anymore because the Request object is now passed in as a parameter. Also note that you don't need to pass any actual arguments when you use the route. The argument is automatically passed in by Laravel.

**UPDATE 2:**

Also, update your Post model with `$fillable` array

```php
<?php 
namespace App; 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; 

class Post extends Model { 
    protected $fillable = ['caption', 'image'];

    public function user(){ 
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class); 
    } 
}
```

The `$fillable` array indicate fields in the database that can be assigned using an HTTP request (e.g. from an HTML form).

From the Laravel documentation:

> you will need to specify either a `fillable` or  `guarded` attribute on the model, as all Eloquent models protect against mass-assignment by default.

Comment: Here is the error I am facing now  "Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST."

Comment: still getting this error Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Comment: Are you sure you have `Route::post('/p', …` and you have updated all relevant code to the answer code?

Comment: Here is in my routes web.php

Comment: Auth::routes();

Route::get('/p/create', 'PostsController@create');
Route::post('/p', 'PostsController@store');

Route::get('/profile/{user}', 'ProfilesController@index')->name('profile.show');

Comment: use `Route::post('/p/store', 'PostsController@store')->name('p.store')` as in the post and update your form action. Also, about your image file, I've updated the validation logic. What are you storing to the database?  Is it the image file path?

Comment: is the file path the routes?

Comment: No, it isn't. It is the path where the image is stored on the server file system. I'm asking about what should be stored im the image field in the `Post` table.  Also, are you still getting `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` error?

Comment: It will store pictures like posts cause I am trying to duplicate instagram using laravel so that I can understand the concept

Comment: Ok, let's focus first on the error. Do this in your store method `dd($request->all()); Post::create($request->input());` put the dd before the create(). and see if you still have the error. Also try removing both the dd and create() lines and leave only the validation code in the store() and test for the error again.

Comment: Still it is. This symphony error is still popping up

Comment: Also, let me see your `Post` model class definition. Do you have this line - `protected $fillable = ['caption', 'image'];`

Comment: <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}

Comment: Sorry that isn't the model. The model should usually be in `app/Post.php`. you can check it out.

Comment: Ok I see it in the comment. But you don't have any `$fillables`? I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your route. Both your get and post route are going to the controller's create method. Post route will be like

```
Route::post('/p', 'PostsController@store');
```

Comment: Still it is. Is laravel so complicated. I am still new programmer